# AngularJS - Dynamic CSS Value

Tags: css, angularjs

It seems that numeric values initiated using `ng-init` works with CSS attribute as seen on the sample using `myHeight` variable.

However, the variable `event` doesn't seem to work. Even with the value set to `none`, the hover effect is still triggered when hovered in the element:

```css
.has-hover {
  background-color: red;
}

.has-hover:hover {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app ng-init="myHeight=100; event=none">
  <div class="has-hover" style="height: {{myHeight}}px; pointer-events: {{event}};" >
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `ng-style` for this. Also, I think you need to set `event` equal to the string `'none'`:

```css
.has-hover {
  background-color: red;
}

.has-hover:hover {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app ng-init="myHeight=100; event='none'">
  <div class="has-hover" ng-style="{ height: myHeight + 'px', 'pointer-events': event }">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `ng-style` 
like this

```
ng-style="{'height': myHeight + 'px','pointer-events':event}"
```